# Rationale to keep std::mutex lock/unlock public

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

My question is simple. In C++11 we have `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock`.

The usual way to use these classes is to lock the `std::mutex` through any of the locks. This prevents leaking mutexes due to exception throwing:

```
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(some_mutex);
   //Cannot leak mutex.
}
```

Why `std::mutex::lock` and `std::mutex::unlock` are public? That calls for incorrect usage:

```
{ 
     some_mutex.lock();
     //Mutex leaked due to exception.
     some_mutex.unlock();
}
```

Wouldn't be safer to make `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` a friend of `std::mutex` and make `std::mutex` lock operations private? This would prevent unsafe usage.

The only reason I can guess for this design is that if I have my own lock, it couldn't be used with `std::mutex` because I wouldn't be able to make my own lock friend of `std::mutex`. Is this the main reason behind making these member functions public?

Comment: Somebody from the committee (e.g., Howard Hinnant) *might* have a real answer, but most people can probably only speculate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rationale for this design decision is documented in [N2406](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html#mutex_rationale):

> Unlike boost, the mutexes have public member functions for lock(),
>   unlock(), etc. This is necessary to support one of the primary goals:
>   User defined mutexes can be used with standard defined locks. If there
>   were no interface for the user defined mutex to implement, there would
>   be no way for a standard defined lock to communicate with the user
>   defined mutex.

At the time this was written, boost::mutex could only be locked and unlocked with boost::scoped_lock.

So you can now write `my::mutex`, and as long as you supply members `lock()` and `unlock()`, your `my::mutex` is just as much a first class citizen as `std::mutex`.  Your clients can use `std::unique_lock<my::mutex>` just as easily as they can use `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`, even though `std::unique_lock` has no clue what `my::mutex` is.

A motivating real-life example of `my::mutex` is the proposed `std::shared_mutex` now in the C++1y (we hope y == 4) [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf).  `std::shared_mutex` has members `lock()` and `unlock()` for the exclusive-mode locking and unlocking.  And it interacts with `std::unique_lock` when the client uses `std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>` just as expected.

And just in case you might believe `shared_mutex` might be the only other motivating mutex that could make use of this generic interface, here's another real-world example: :-)

```
template <class L0, class L1>
void
lock(L0& l0, L1& l1)
{
    while (true)
    {
        {
            unique_lock<L0> u0(l0);
            if (l1.try_lock())
            {
                u0.release();
                break;
            }
        }
        this_thread::yield();
        {
            unique_lock<L1> u1(l1);
            if (l0.try_lock())
            {
                u1.release();
                break;
            }
        }
        this_thread::yield();
    }
}
```

This is the basic code for how to lock (in an exception safe manner) two BasicLockables at once, without danger of deadlock.  And despite many critiques to the contrary, this code is *extraordinarily*  efficient.

Note the line in the code above:

```
            unique_lock<L0> u0(l0);
```

This algorithm has no clue what type `L0` is.  But as long as it supports `lock()` and `unlock()` (ok and `try_lock()` too), everything is cool.  `L0` might even be another instantiation of `unique_lock`, perhaps `unique_lock<my::mutex>` or even `unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>`, or perhaps even `std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>`.

It all just works.  And all because there is no intimate relationship between `std::unique_lock` and `std::mutex` aside from the agreed upon public interface of `lock()` and `unlock()`.

Comment: "Unlike boost, the mutexes have public member functions for lock(), unlock(), etc..." If my understanding is correct, making `std::mutex::lock` and unlock operations non-public does not mean I couldn't define `my::mutex` and wouldn't work. What I mean is that `std::mutex` could have `private` lock and unlock and be made `friend` of the locks to prevent misuse.

Comment: What I mean is: in which way doing `std::mutex::lock` and unlock `private` prevent my own classes of having a public member `lock` and `unlock` for `my::mutex`. This would still work and would make `std::mutex` less dangerous to use for the average user, because they wouldn't be able to misuse it.

Comment: @GermánDiago - there's nothing inherently dangerous about explicitly locking and unlocking a mutex. At some point programmers are responsible for writing correct code.

Comment: @GermánDiago:  The industry tried it your way in the original design of `boost::mutex` and `boost::scoped_lock`.  And to a large extent that design worked.  But people complained more than they are now about the current design.  The current design is built upon years of actual field experience, and changing things when that experience is negative.  That is the rationale for why things are the way they are.  You can also wrap `std::mutex` with `my::safe_mutex`, giving your version private members if that is what works best for you.

Comment: I still didn't see the definitive answer to my question, which is, concretely, this: why can't we make `std::mutex::lock` and unlock private and standard locks `friend`. This would prevent locking with another lock, not a big deal in my opinion. But this wouldn't prevent me from defining a `my::mutex` with public lock and unlock operations. This would be better for a) safer use in most cases (exception-safe). b) still possible to use custom mutexes. This doesn't prevent either of having a `lockable` concept as there is currently. If I'm wrong, correct me, please.

Comment: I will take it as a reply finally, but still not convinced completely about my last question in this comment :-)

Answer (score 3):

As Jerry Coffin pointed out, we can only speculate without an actual committee member chiming in, but my guess would be that they designed the interfaces with flexibility and the ability to extend them in your own way in mind.  Instead of making every potential class a friend of `std::mutex`, exposing the interface to do the needed operations allows for someone (e.g. boost contributors) to come along and find a new and better way to do something with it.  If the interface was hidden, that would not be possible.